# What to do if my href links are not opening in separate tabs?

Tags: html, hyperlink, href

I have linked my tags to two social media sites but they are opening in the same tabs instead of separate ones

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/gidclass" target="blank"><span class="icon-facebook text-teal"></span></a>
 <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCHpajI05rxsaXu-HnMF4HXA" target="blank"><span class="icon-youtube text-teal"></span></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

`target="blank"` changes to `target="_blank"`

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/gidclass" target="_blank"><span class="icon-facebook text-teal"></span></a>
 <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCHpajI05rxsaXu-HnMF4HXA" target="_blank"><span class="icon-youtube text-teal"></span></a>
```